# Select-Object -ExpandProperty issue

Tags: powershell, select-object

I have run into an issue that the output from 2 users are not identical when running a PowerShell script as belew. Does anyone how to fix the issue for user B to get the same result of User A ?

```
Get-Mailbox hkgbsdis-3130501 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ForwardingAddress
```

- Result from user A

  ```
  IsDeleted         : False
  Rdn               : CN=sgBS_EmailClient_MIC_HKY_forward
  Parent            : mydomain.com/TempOU/OU-BSeMailStorageGroups
  Depth             : 4
  DistinguishedName : CN=sgBS_EmailClient_MIC_HKY_forward,OU=OU-BSeMailStorageGroups,OU=TempOU,DC=mydomain,DC=com
  IsRelativeDn      : False
  DomainId          : mydomain.com
  ObjectGuid        : 0e4ee5e6-dd33-4033-b091-29153a6f5ec3
  Name              : sgBS_EmailClient_MIC_HKY_forward
  ```
- Result from user B

  ```
  mydomain.com/TempOU/OU-BSeMailStorageGroups/sgBS_EmailClient_MIC_HKY_forward
  ```

Comment: Try to add: `... | Select-Object -Properry *`

Comment: Thanks but it looks even worst.  It only shows the "Length" property with a number instead.   Why user B cannot show the details like User A ?  Is there any PS setup I can do on User B ?

Comment: I just noticed that User A's workstation returned a "ADObjectId" but User B's workstation returned a "String" type.  How can I trigger User B's workstation to return a "ADObjectId" as well ?

Comment: Are you showing us everything that you are executing?  The one line of PS code looks to be running only against a single mailbox.  How are you executing this against multiple mailboxes?

Comment: Yes but this is the main cause of the problem.  In fact, I execute this cmdlet from the PS Window and these are the result from both machines.

Comment: Does anyone know the reason ?